# My Android EditText class is appearing without "edit box"

Tags: android, class, coding-style, android-edittext

I am doing a custom editbox class. It starts something like:

```
public class AmountField extends EditText {
```

and has overriden the constructor to implement the EditText widget style

```
/**
 * Make a new AmountField Object.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context of the field
 * @param attrs
 *            attributes for the view
 */
public AmountField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.style.Widget_EditText);
}
```

However when I implement this on my XML I get an editable TextView instead of the EditText (there is only text but not the surrounding white box) and also when I click on it nothing happens, only text color changes.

Are there any ideas on why this happens? I've done list components the same way and style is not altered.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, i have just realized that the constructor must call super instead of other constructor with more parameters.